# FakeAppUpdateManager - No longer working on API 31+, does not specify mutability flag when creating PendingIntent, when fetching appUpdateInfo

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-core, android-api-31

Using PlayCoreKtx version 1.8.1,

I have an instrumented test that tests the inAppUpdate functionality of Play Core. I have a function in my test that looks like this

```
private fun processAvailableUpdate(appUpdateType: AppUpdateType) = mainActivityScenario.onActivity { mainActivity ->
    AppUpdater.processAvailableUpdate(
        mainActivity,
        AppUpdateResult.Available(
            fakeAppUpdateManager,
            Tasks.await(fakeAppUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo)
        ), appUpdateType
    )
}
```

I am getting the following exception on the line

```
Tasks.await(fakeAppUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo)
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.

I assume there is no going around this until it is fixed in the PlayCore library? Unless I am missing something.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is fixed in

```
com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3
```

If you only had

```
com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1
```

in your dependencies, then you had this error. So make sure to add both dependencies to your gradle file.